# pandas pivot_table's margins is only aggregating vertically

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Consider a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'last_year': [1, 2, 3], 'next_year': [4, 5, 6]}, 
    index=['foo', 'bar', 'star']
)
```

```
      last_year  next_year
foo           1          4
bar           2          5
star          3          6
```

**I am looking for an easy way to display totals around this table, both column and row wise.**

My thought was to throw it through `.pivot_table()`:

```py
pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=df.index,
    margins=True,
    aggfunc=sum
)
```

However, this only works for the first axis (vertically):

```
      last_year  next_year
bar           2          5
foo           1          4
star          3          6
All           6         15
```

What did I miss? How come no row wise totals are calculated as well, just like in [this documentation's example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#adding-margins)? Also, why is it messing up my index' order?

I'm not interested in `df['All'] = df.sum(axis=1)` kind of solutions; I want a dynamic approach which does not affect my original dataframe. A pivot table seems like the most logical way to do this (as far as I know) but maybe there are better ways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that each column is its own group in `pivot_table` so you don't see the horizontal aggregation (it's rather pointless to aggregate one single element). To demonstrate the difference, consider `stack()`:

```
(df.stack().reset_index(name='value')
   .pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values='value', margins=True,
               aggfunc='sum')
)
```

Output:

```
level_1  last_year  next_year  All
level_0                           
bar              2          5    7
foo              1          4    5
star             3          6    9
All              6         15   21
```

That said, it might very well be a bug.

Comment: Hmm, actually because of passing `index=` and not `columns=` as being the grouper object I'd expect those groups to be aggregated, meaning horizontal totals!

Comment: OK I get your answer now, it took @Andy L.'s thorough explanation to figure out that I need to 'unpivot' `last_year` and `next_year` before being able to aggregate them. Looking at `df.stack().reset_index()` without pivoting makes that clear.

Answer (score 5):

When you don't specify `values` and `columns` parameters in `pivot_table`. It will use all columns for `values`. Since you specify only `index` parameter, the rest of columns which are columns `last_year`, `next_year` are used as values for aggregation. I.e., Pandas thinks you want to apply `sum` function on values of columns `last_year`, `next_year`

Since all columns of `df` are all used for `values` parameter, `pivot_table` doesn't pivot anything to column (axis=1). Therefore, there is no reason for it to do `margins` on `axis=1`.

Try on this sample

```
Out[132]:
      last_year  next_year
foo           1          4
bar           2          5
star          3          6
bar          33         66

pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, margins=True, aggfunc=sum)

Out[134]:
      last_year  next_year
bar          35         71
foo           1          4
star          3          6
All          39         81
```

So, `pivot_table` applies sum on both columns `last_year`,  `next_year` on each group of `index` which sum `bar` to `35` and `71` and finally it computes `margins` on axis=0. There is no pivoting to axis=1 so it doesn't do `margins` on axis=1.

To see that pivot_table use all columns for `values` parameter, you may try this command to see the keyerror

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, margins=True, aggfunc={'last_year': sum})

.....
    220                     grand_margin[k] = getattr(v, aggfunc)()
    221                 elif isinstance(aggfunc, dict):
--> 222                     if isinstance(aggfunc[k], compat.string_types):
    223                         grand_margin[k] = getattr(v, aggfunc[k])()
    224                     else:

KeyError: 'next_year'
```

When using dict for aggfunc, `pivot_table` passes each column in `values` parameter to the dict to get the accordingly aggfunc. As you see above, I don't specify column `next_year` in the dict. Therefore, when pivot_table looking for its aggfunc in the dict, it returns keyerror.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, this helped me see what's truly going on.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'last_year': [1, 2, 3], 'next_year': [4, 5, 6]}, 
    index=['foo', 'bar', 'star']
)

df.append(df.sum().rename('Total')).assign(Total=lambda d: d.sum(1))
```

OUTPUT:

```
     last_year   next_year   Total
foo      1           4         5
bar      2           5         7
star     3           6         9
Total    6          15        21
```

This doesn't affect the original dataframe!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but I made the columns and rows switched in order to make aggregated totals. For improved code, can you explain more in-depth that a dynamic approach? Thanks and I hope this helps!

```
df43 = pd.DataFrame(
{'last_year': [1, 2, 3], 'next_year': [4, 5, 6]}, 
index=['foo', 'bar', 'star'])
df43 = df43.T #.T is transpose
df43['total'] = df43.sum(axis=1)
df43
```

Comment: I explicitly state that I am not looking for `df.sum(axis=1)` answers. Why is `.pivot_table()` not behaving like in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

To see row totals you need to specify at least one argument to columns=

So:

pd.pivot_table(
df,
index=df.index,
margins=True,
columns='last_year'
aggfunc=sum
)

...will give you also row totals as well as the existing column totals you already have. Not that it makes sense in your specific example. But basically pandas pivot  will only give you row totals if you pivoted at least one column.

The documentation example that you linked to, works (has row totals) because it specifies a value for columns=.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).